# How comes the C++ standards committee introduces a keyword like nullptr and gets away with it?

Tags: c++, standards, standardization

That must have broken a lot of peoples code bases right?
Everyone who had a variable named "nullptr" (which I think would have been fairly common) has to find "nullptr" and replace with "something_else" before being able to compile with c++11.

Does the standards committee assume that people will do that much "adjusting"?

Comment: "Get away?" They're the standards committee, they make the rules. What are people going to do, topple them and rule themselves? Most committee members see the task as a necessary chore and would *love* to be replaced by others willing to put in the work.

Comment: "How many breaking changes were introduced? That many? Well one more wouldn't hurt, right?"

Comment: @KilianFoth I deeply apologise if the wording of my question caused you hurt.

Comment: I think it's standard and accepted practice that updating your code base to a newer standard is likely to involve at least some level of re-writing. It's not just variable names - what if part of your code turned out to be reliant on a bug or behaivour that has now been fixed/altered/removed?

Comment: @ratchetfreak Actually there weren't *that [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11)*

Comment: That's what happens when people use bad variable names. `nullptr` is one of them

Comment: @faif At the risk of asking something that might be slightly off topic on this thread; what makes `nullptr` a bad variable name ?

Comment: @Wildling when `nullptr` isn't `NULL` then something is wrong with your code on a more fundamental problem

Comment: @wildling It's too generic, says nothing about the context (null pointer of what to what?), violates the common coding standards (I would expect null_ptr or nullPtr), and I agree with the last comment of @ratchetfreak (what happens if the value of the variable is not `NULL`?)

Comment: I guess that the standard committee spent days discussing the choice of that particular `nullptr` keyword.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Do they record their minute of meetings or something ? I mean it would be really exciting how they finalise decisions like this.

Comment: The committe website is at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/, and they have meeting minutes in their "mailings" section (along with all the proposals).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The C++ standards committee is full of smart people that are fully aware of the amount of existing code and the consequences of introducing new keywords.

One of the aims of the committee is to keep as much existing code as possible working unchanged and that certainly plays a large role when deciding to add new keywords and how to name those keywords.

To my knowledge, when a new keyword is proposed, they perform an investigation over a number of large codebases to see how many conflicts that new keyword would create and if any of those conflicts would create a silent change in the behavior of the programs.

According to the [proposal for adding `nullptr`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2214.pdf), this spelling of the keyword resulted in the least amount of conflict with existing code:

> - Programmers have often requested that the null pointer constant have a name, and `nullptr` appears to be the least likely of the alternative text spellings to conflict with identifiers in existing user programs. For example, a Google search for `nullptr cpp` returns a total of merely 150 hits, only one of which appears to use `nullptr` in a C++ program.
>
>   - The alternative name `NULL` is not available. `NULL` is already the name of an implementation-defined macro in the C and C++ standards. If we defined `NULL` to be a keyword, it would still be replaced by macros lurking in older code. Also, there might be code “out there” that (unwisely) depended on `NULL` being `0`. Finally, identifiers in all caps are conventionally assumed to be macros, testable by `#ifdef`, etc.
>   - The alternative name `null` is impractical. It is nearly as bad as `NULL` in that `null` is also a commonly used in existing programs as an identifier name and (worse)
>       as a macro name. For example, a Google search for `null cpp` returns about 180,000 hits, of which an estimated 3% or over 5,000 use `null` in C++ code as an identifier or as a macro. Another favorite, `nil`, is worse still.
>   - Any other name we have thought of is longer or clashes more often.

Given this analysis, I don't expect that that much adjustment needs to be done.
But otherwise, yes you are expected to update your codebase for the backwards-incompatible changes when moving to a new standard.

Comment: I just wonder, can you give some sources for their sweeps of a number of large codebases or is this smart guessing of best practise?

Comment: @Trilarion: I don't have any numbers. It is based on inference from snippets of online conversations.

Answer (score 5):

Introducing new language features and extensions, most of the time, require new language keywords or syntax changes. In addition, its essential to name these keywords for their intended purposes so as to help programmers memorize the new features. Fortunately, for that purpose, new language version/standards contain a list of **code-breaking changes** that you must consult before building the code with the new toolset.

Comment: There are even [migrator tools](http://blog.llvm.org/2013/04/status-of-c11-migrator.html) which especially warn in the case of nullptr.